# Send specific request uri to subdirectory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I need to find a way to redirect all requests that contain the following URL:

http://local.testdomain/quality/

to use the appropriate files in {Document_Root}/quality/

ie. user requests   http://local.testdomain/quality/assets/images/35.jpg

needs to get the file {public_folder}/quality/assets/images/35.jpg

What I've tried in the .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.testdomain$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !quality/
RewriteRule (.*) /quality/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
I basically want to put a whole php project in Zend's public folder, and have that php project attainable via that request uri ({domain}/quality/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems your htaccess is not correct.

Try something like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local.testdomain$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/quality/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PATH_TO_YOUR_PUBLIC_FOLDER/quality/$1 [L]
```

Let me know if it works

Best,